# Входящие данные в asyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Необходимо содержимое inText передать в AsyncTask. Как я понял в doInBackground(Void... params), void заменить на String, то params будет массивом. А мне просто необходимо передать одну строку. Как это сделать?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new ParseTask().execute();

    outText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.out_text);
    inText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.in_text);

}

public class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // работа с json
        return resultJson;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
        super.onPostExecute(strJson);
        //парсинг
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда мы указываем аргументы метода как `String... params`, это означает, что в него можно передать один объект `String`, несколько объектов `String` через запятую или массив таких объектов. Обращаться же к ним из метода следует по индексам.

[Пример](https://ideone.com/gOPFu9):

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    example("abc");
    example("aaa", "bbb", "ccc");
    String[] arr = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};
    example(arr);
}

public static void example(String... params) {
    System.out.println(params[0]);
}
```

Выведет:

```
abc
aaa
aaa
```

Так что смело заменяйте `Void` на `String`.

Соответственно в методе onCreate код будет выглядеть так:

```
inText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.in_text);
new ParseTask().execute(inText.getText().toString());
```